# Material UI Homepage Theme?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, theming

I have attached an image of the demo that is displayed on the main page for Material UI. I really like this theme and I want to use one like it with MUI to create my web application. Is there any way that I can use this theme (style my components like this) or do I have to replicate it from scratch?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the code for that theme here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.8.0/docs/src/modules/brandingTheme.ts.

You can see it used here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.8.0/docs/src/BrandingProvider.tsx#L23.

I've created a code sandbox that demonstrates using this theme: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-docs-theme-example-0mys5d?file=/index.tsx. `brandingTheme.ts` in the sandbox is an exact copy of the file in GitHub. It is then used from within `index.tsx` in the sandbox. `demo.tsx` just shows a few different components in order to see the theme in action.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to implement your own fancy theme, you can **simply** customize the MUI theme using [theming](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/) or even modify components' style [like this!](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/).

Take a look at [premium template](https://mui.com/store/) if you want to buy something.

There are also a few free themes you may find just but googling like:

[Free React Dashboard...](https://mui.com/store/collections/free-react-dashboard/)